# Where do I need to place the ng4-autocomplete 'settings' code from the documentation?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have to implement autocomplete for a text input that takes addresses/locations in Angular 4.

I found this package on Google, https://tanoy009.github.io/ng4-geoautocomplete/, but I am not sure where to place the settings part of example3 in my own code. This is what I have so far:

export class TestComponent {

```
apiAddress: string = "";

@Output() notify: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();

autoCompleteCallback1(selectedData: any) {


    this.apiAddress = selectedData.description;

    this.notify.emit(this.apiAddress);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look at the documentation. It's very clear.

https://github.com/tanoy009/ng4-geoautocomplete#installation

> Installation
>
> Install through npm:
>
> `npm install --save ng4-geoautocomplete Then include in your apps`
>
> module:
>
> ```
> import { Component, NgModule } from '@angular/core'; import {
> Ng4GeoautocompleteModule } from 'ng4-geoautocomplete';
>
> @NgModule({   
>      imports: [
>         Ng4GeoautocompleteModule.forRoot()   
>      ] 
> }) 
> export class MyModule{}
> ```
>
> Add google place script in your main file generally referred to
>       'index.html' (Optional if you want to use google services).
>
> ```
> <script type="text/javascript"
> src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true&key=XXReplace
> this with valid keyXX&libraries=places&language=en-US"></script>
> ```
>
> Finally use in one of your apps components:
>
> ```
> import { Component } from '@angular/core';
>
> @Component({   template: '<ng4geo-autocomplete
>     (componentCallback)="autoCompleteCallback1($event)"></ng4geo-
>     autocomplete>'
> })
>
> export class MyComponent {    
>    autoCompleteCallback1(selectedData:any) {      
>              //do any necessery stuff.    
>    } 
> }
> ```

UPDATE: The next part of the answer is an update placed here to answer the question in the comment section.

The following links show the code for the demo you linked. This will tell you where to put the settings. You basically create settings in your component's typescript file and then use them in the html.

**TypeScript**

```
  public userSettings2: any = {
    showRecentSearch: false,
    geoCountryRestriction: ['in'],
    searchIconUrl: 'http://downloadicons.net/sites/default/files/identification-search-magnifying-glass-icon-73159.png'
  };
```

**HTML**

```
<ng4geo-autocomplete [userSettings]="userSettings2" (componentCallback)="autoCompleteCallback2($event)"></ng4geo-autocomplete>
```

https://github.com/tanoy009/ng4-geoautocomplete/blob/master/demo/demo.component.ts

https://github.com/tanoy009/ng4-geoautocomplete/blob/master/demo/demo.component.html

Comment: yes , i have all these things and got output. But i need to use this object.{
"showCurrentLocation":false,
"resOnSearchButtonClickOnly":true,
"inputPlaceholderText":"This is delayed test",
"recentStorageName":"componentData3",
"inputString":"Bangalore,
karnataka"
}.

where i need to place this code.

Comment: pls tell me where to place settings given in the link.

Comment: pls send some code sample by implementing in the call back. I have tried in so many ways. but did not get the result.

Comment: I have updated the answer to reflect your further questions.

Comment: @balajik If this answer fixed your problem, please mark it as the accepted answer so others who may face the same issue can see that a solution exists.

Comment: @ChrisSharp , Could you advice how to clear ng4geo-autocomplete input after user chose city?

Comment: @Nick - check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46268259/clear-angular-material-autocomplete-after-selection